# Linking a qtDesigner .ui file to python/pyqt?

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

So if I go into QtDesigner and build a UI, it'll be saved as a .ui file.  How can I make this as a python file or use this in python?

Comment: I have used the PySide QUiLoader to achieve just that - see post [4442286][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442286

Comment: The following method is even more practical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892713/how-do-you-load-ui-files-onto-python-classes-with-pyside/14894550#14894550

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Another way to use .ui in your code is:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget)
    ...
    #somewhere in constructor:
    uic.loadUi('MyWidget.ui', self)
```

both approaches are good. Do not forget, that if you use Qt resource files (extremely useful) for icons and so on, you must compile it too:

```
pyrcc4.exe -o ui/images_rc.py ui/images/images.qrc
```

Note, when `uic` compiles interface, it adds 'import images_rc' at the end of .py file, so you must compile resources into the file with this name, or rename it in generated code.

Comment: Could you add how to access a variable in once you've done? Such as pushButton?

Comment: @JonathanLeaders If there is a button defined in .ui file, you just call it like this: self.pushButton. You can also load ui to any class attribute you want: uic.loadUi('uifile.ui', self.ui) and call widgets and stuff like self.ui.pushButton.

Answer (score 55):

Combining [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500905/544059) and [Shriramana Sharma's mailing list post](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2007-April/015902.html), I built a small working example for loading a `mywindow.ui` file containing a `QMainWindow` (so just choose to create a Main Window in Qt Designer's `File-New` dialog).

This is the code that loads it:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mywindow.ui', self)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This should be the best answer, because it is a complete example.

Answer (score 30):

You need to generate a python file from your ui file with the pyuic tool (site-packages\pyqt4\bin)

```
pyuic form1.ui > form1.py
```

with pyqt4

```
pyuic4.bat form1.ui > form1.py
```

Then you can import the form1 into your script.

Answer (score 25):

I found this article very helpful.

http://talk.maemo.org/archive/index.php/t-43663.html

I'll briefly describe the actions to create and change .ui file to .py file, taken from that article.

1. Start Qt Designer from your start menu.
2. From "New Form" window, create "Main Window"
3. From "Display Widgets" towards the bottom of your "Widget Box Menu" on the left hand side
   add a "Label Widget". (Click Drag and Drop)
4. Double click on the newly added Label Widget to change its name to "Hello World"
5. at this point you can use Control + R hotkey to see how it will look.
6. Add buttons or text or other widgets by drag and drop if you want.
7. Now save your form.. File->Save As-> "Hello World.ui" (Control + S  will also bring up
   the "Save As" option)  Keep note of the directory where you saved your "Hello World" .ui
   file. (I saved mine in (C:) for convenience)

The file is created and saved, now we will Generate the Python code from it using pyuic!

1. From your start menu open a command window.
2. Now "cd" into the directory where you saved your "Hello World.ui" For me i just had to 
   "cd\" and was at my "C:>" prompt, where my "Hello World.ui" was saved to.
3. When you get to the directory where your file is stored type the following.
4. pyuic4 -x helloworld.ui -o helloworld.py
5. Congratulations!! You now have a python Qt4 GUI application!!
6. Double click your helloworld.py file to run it. ( I use pyscripter and upon double click
   it opens in pyscripter, then i "run" the file from there)

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I was compiling using: pyuic4 helloworld.ui > helloworld.py. One really has to pass -x and -o arguments to pyuic4. Thanks for the information!.

Comment: Great explanation, especially that the "generation of the GUI"-code is actually in the generated file helped me out, cheers!

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `uic` in PyQt5 with the following code.

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('SomeUi.ui', self)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 13):

The cleaner way in my opinion is to first export to .py as aforementioned:

```
pyuic4 foo.ui > foo.py
```

And then use it inside your code (e.g `main.py`), like:

```
from foo import Ui_MyWindow


class MyWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MyWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # go on setting up your handlers like:
        # self.ui.okButton.clicked.connect(function_name)
        # etc...

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This way gives the ability to other people who don't use qt-designer to read the code, and also keeps your functionality code outside `foo.py` that could be overwritten by designer. You just reference `ui` through `MyWindow` class as seen above.

Comment: `self.ui.okButton.clicked.connect(self.function_name)` gives me  `TypeError: event() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 9):

You can convert your .ui files to an executable python file using the below command..

```
pyuic4 -x form1.ui > form1.py
```

Now you can straightaway execute the python file as

```
python3(whatever version) form1.py
```

You can import this file and you can use it.

Comment: FYI If you omit the -x option you will not get the portion of the code that creates and runs the application.  I have seen a few answers which omit "-x".  This answer is the most complete.

Answer (score 5):

you can compile the ui files like this

```
pyuic4 -x helloworld.ui -o helloworld.py
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to compile .ui files to .py files, I did:

```
python pyuic.py form1.ui > form1.py
```

Att.

Answer (score 3):

in pyqt5 to convert from a ui file to .py file

`pyuic5.exe youruifile.ui -o outputpyfile.py -x`

Answer (score 1):

(**November 2020**) This worked for me (**UBUNTU 20.04**):

```
pyuic5 /home/someuser/Documents/untitled.ui > /home/someuser/Documents/untitled.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Anaconda3 (September 2018) and QT designer 5.9.5.
In QT designer, save your file as ui.
Open Anaconda prompt. Search for your file: cd C:.... (copy/paste the access path of your file).
Then write: pyuic5 -x helloworld.ui -o helloworld.py (helloworld = name of your file). Enter.
Launch Spyder. Open your file .py.