# How can I include ui and image files while using py2exe?

Tags: windows, py2exe, pyside

I am working on a project using Python 2.7 and PySide 1.1.2. My code is working without any problem on my GNU/Linux but I want to distribute for Windows ( 7 and 8 ) as well. I can't expect users to install Python and PySide, so I decided to use py2exe (I also tried cx_freeze and pyinstaller).

First of all, here is my file tree: [My Project on GitHub](https://github.com/th0th/metusuite/tree/experimental)

I created a setup.py, here it is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['bin/metusuite.py'],
    name='metusuite',
    version='0.1',
    author='H. Gökhan Sarı',
    author_email='me@th0th.me',
    packages=['metusuite_libs'],
    package_dir={'metusuite_libs': 'metusuite_libs'},
    package_data={'metusuite_libs': ['ui/*', 'images/*']},
    scripts=['bin/metusuite.py'],
    url='https://github.com/th0th/metusuite/',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='METU Suite.',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
)
```

When I run

```
setup.py py2exe
```

it successfully builds metusuite.exe in 'dist' folder, however, since application depends on external user interface files -created with Qt Designer- and it can't find them, I get an error:

```
Designer: An error has occurred while reading the UI file at line 1, column 0: Premature end of document.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metusuite.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "metusuite_libs\msCafeteriaMenu.pyc", line 37, in __init__
  File "metusuite_libs\msCafeteriaMenu.pyc", line 17, in __init__
RuntimeError: Unable to open/read ui device
```

And I couldn't figure out how am I supposed to add *.ui files (also there are some .png icons) into that structure. I was thinking of converting .ui files to Python code, then I would have encounter same issue when I need to add some icons.

Hence, how can I add my ui and png files in py2exe structure? Or is there any alternative method for what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 10):

Well, I think you could do one of two realistic things:

1. Compile your .ui files to .py files using [pyside-uic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442286/python-code-genration-with-pyside-uic) and modify your code to do conditional loading of the py files for the user interface and place the png files in a Qt Resource file
2. Create a Qt Resource file with your ui files inside of it, compile that with pyside-rcc, and then load the ui files using QtUiTools or some similar process

## `pyside-uic`

I greatly prefer using the `pyside-uic` method for loading ui files because it is the most straightforward way of loading ui files into a program that correlates with my knowledge of Qt in C++. `pyside-uic` is included with the PySide applications and for me it is found in the Scripts directory of my Python installation, e.g. `C:\Python27\Scripts\pyside-uic.exe`. Taking a note from how C++ compilation handles ui files, I typically compile my ui files to have a name like ui_[Name of the ui file].py:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pyside-uic mainwindow.ui > ui_mainwindow.py
```

Inside of that resulting .py file, pyside-uic creates a class named the same name as the base class of the ui file prepended with Ui_. So, for instance, if you created a mainwindow.ui that contained the definition for a class named MainWindow, the created class would be Ui_MainWindow. If the ui file defined a class named SourceWindow, the class within the .py file Ui_SourceWindow. In Qt Designer you set the class name by setting `objectName` in the root element of the object tree (in the upper right of the window).

With your files cafeteria_menu,ui and dialog_login.ui, you would get derived classes Ui_cafeteria_menu and Ui_dialog_login.

Once you have the .py file generated, it can be used by importing it into the definition file for your widget and used using the setupUi method of the class in the Ui file

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Once you have ui defined for the class, all of the connections and ui elements for the widget need to be accessed through self.ui

```
        self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged[str].connect(self.processText)
```

Since you would have to put your .png files in a Qt Resource File, I'll talk about it in the next section.

## `pyside-rcc`

Like `pyside-uic`, `pyside-rcc` is included with the PySide application, although mine is in the site-packages directory of Python instead of in Scripts (if it's in the same place for you, you can always copy it).

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PySide\pyside-rcc.exe
```

Before you can compile the Qt Resource File, you have to first create it using one of the Qt Tools. I use Qt Creator since it can perform almost all of the functions related to Qt in one application. The documentation for the [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt/resources.html) shows that the resource file is really just an XML file that defines file paths and internal paths for the resource system. You can set up and organize the files however you want but when it comes to compile, all of the files defined in the Resource File must be in the same directory or a sub-directory of the file. Once you have the Resource File defined, you need to use pyside-rcc.exe to compile it into a .py file. I typically name the resource file the same as the project and keep everything in one resource file to make dealing with the resources more concise.

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PySide\pyside-rcc.exe -py2 MyProject.qrc > MyProject_Resources.py
```

The -py2 switch defines that the output from the file should be formatted for Python 2.x. If you are using Python 3.x or plan to use it in the future, you can use the -py3 switch and the outcome will be compatible with Python 3.x.

## Putting it all together

Since you are already loading the ui files directly `QUiLoader`, you just need to refactor your QUiLoader statements to load a QFile that opens the ui resource from the resource system. To use the files from the resource system, all you need to do is import your Resource .py file, the one generated from pyside-rcc, into the main script file of your program and the last line in the resource file is a call to qInitResources() which initializes the resources to be used in the entire program. To load a file using QFile, use a path that starts with ":" and then references the paths that were defined in the Resource File. You could create a file msResources.qrc that has ui and images that has your ui and png files defined as sub categories.

So, if your resource file looks something like this

```
/ui
    cafeteria_menu.ui
    dialog_login.ui
/images
    cafeteria-menu.png
    exit.png
    logo.png
    mail-fetch.ong
```

And, if you want to load those files, you just need to create a QIcon or QFile like so:

```
cafeteriaMenuIcon = QtGui.QIcon(":/images/cafeteria-menu.png")
cafeteriaMenuUi = QtCore.QFile(":/ui/cafeteria_menu.ui")
```

In use in your code for GUICafeteriaMenu in msCafeteriaMenu, I would just change the `__init__` method for GuiCafeteriaMenu to load and use the ui file from the resources:

```
uiFile = QFile(":/ui/cafeteria_menu.ui")
uiFile.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
UiLoader.load(uiFile, self)
uiFile.close()
```

I would probably place the output from pyside-rcc into the metsuite_libs package into something like msResources.py and import the msResources file in the `__init__.py` file as part of your package. That way, once you have the .py files created and imported into your program, the extra file would be encapsulated in your package and you will not need to change your setup.py file. Before you do the py2exe conversion, running the refactored program should work just fine normally. Additionally, no matter how you handle the ui files, you will always need to use a Resource File to be able to package icons into the program. For portability reasons, using resource files for icons is probably a good habit to get in to.