# motionbuilder 2016 PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, motionbuilder

I have a question about PyQt4 in motionbuilder 2016
I have successfully installed Pyqt4 from pip

and it show up "**have Requirement already satisfied: PyQt4 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (4.11.4)** "

but when import the module in motionbuilder by using import PyQt4
is have  the error : "**ImportError: No module named PyQt4**"

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Motion Builder comes with PySide installed which is PyQt4's alternative version of Python QT library. Try importing from PySide for e.g.

```
from PySide import QtGui
```

[Example](http://docs.autodesk.com/MOBPRO/2016/ENU/MotionBuilder-Developer-Help/index.html#!/url=./py_ref/_u_i_2_tool_native_widget_holder_8py-example.html)

Comment: Thanks Akram,But PySide seem missing come module like 
 => from PyQt4.uic import loadUi 
do you have any way to get it?

Comment: Use pyside uic to convert the UI file into python module and import it into your code. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442286/python-code-generation-with-pyside-uic

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the problem and solved
Uninstall the Python2.7 and reinstall again, getting the new version of Pip, install the whl file by using pip
it solved, i think is my sys.path mass up!