# Call functions in PyDev Eclipse in form generated by Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer

python version 3.3.2

ide: PyDev Eclipse with PyQt installed

I designed a gui in Qt Designer, saved the .ui file and convert it into python code with this command:

```
pyuic4 -x DeA.ui -o DeA.py
```

[image: my designed gui in Qt Designer]

Qt Designer xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>485</width>
    <height>374</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_add">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Add item</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QListView" name="lst">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>461</width>
      <height>301</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

pyuic4 final python gui output:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'DeA.ui'
#
# Created: Tue Jun  4 03:30:45 2013
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(485, 374)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.btn_add = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_add.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 121, 41))
        self.btn_add.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_add"))
        self.lst = QtGui.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.lst.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 461, 301))
        self.lst.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lst"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.btn_add.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add item", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

then I copy and paste the content of newly created python file(“DeA.py”) into my python file in PyDev Eclipse and hit Run, and gui shows up just fine;

[image: PyDev Eclipse and final outcome of my gui code]

**my questions:**

where exactly in PyDev Eclipse script pane (not using slots in Qt Designer) can I add my own python functions so that when I hit the “Add item” button, it adds 100 items into the ListView?

I found this question: [Linking a qtDesigner .ui file to python/pyqt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398800/linking-a-qtdesigner-ui-file-to-python-pyqt) about linking the .ui file into the final project and build gui at run time; but I couldn’t understand it; Please help; what exactly should I add into my PyDev Eclipse script pane to link the .ui file and build it at runtime? (suppose the .ui file path is: D:\DeA.ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not have to actually convert the .ui file to .py to use it,
you can do something like this..

lest say that my .ui file is

"C:/mydesign.ui"

```
from PyQt4  import QtGui
from PyQt4  import QtCore
from PyQt4  import uic
import sys

FORM_1, BASE_1 = uic.loadUiType(r"C:/mydesign.ui")

APP = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MyApp(FORM_1, BASE_1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.btn_add, QtCore.SIGNAL("released()"), self.do_something)

    def do_something(self):
        print "working"


FORM = MyApp()
FORM.show()
APP.exec_()
```