# How do i found QPushButton in uic.load() *.ui file?

Tags: pyqt4

```
from images import mainwindow
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QMainWindow

class mainwindow_ui(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          QMainWindow.__init__(self)
          self.ui = uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui',self)
          button = self.ui.exitBtn
          self.ui.show()
```

How to interactive with button object on Python console?

Tab completion work.
After tab press, there is no mainwindow_ui.exitBtn - or mainwindow.button  why?

Comment: Use the uic utility to convert the file from .ui to .py as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python. Then you'll be able to import the .py file directly instead (which will allow code completion).

Comment: Oh, then you shouldn't need to load mainwindow.ui at all. I'd recommend looking at some basic PyQt tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

uic.loadUi essentially loading the widget name into the classes namespace.

if you named the widget "foo" from within Qdesigner then you can access  it via **self.foo**