# QT designer didn't install uic program for view the code from the application

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface, pyqt4

i installed Qt designer 4,  created a small windows with buttons, now when i click view code...

i get the message

```
unable to lunch C:Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4\uic.
```

i check the folder and i dont see any uic files,  i have a uic folder with bunch of python files,  want to be able to see the code thats is been generated, yes, i understand that will be in C++ and thats what i want to see.      UIC is not installed?   should i have c compiler?  should i download it from somewhere else?

should i never use qt designer any more and just go for qt creator?

thanks guys.

Comment: The PyQt binary package for Windows does not install the full set of [Qt command-line tools](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qttools.html). Specifically, `uic.exe` is not included, which is why you are seeing that error message.

Comment: k, i installed qt5 with qt creator and i do see now the uic.exe file,   i copy paste it to the python27>libs>site-packages>PyQt4  and also to the UIC folder,    i still have the same error =(  can i change the path in qt designer to use the UIC path of qt creator?  thanks =)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue using Qt Designer and found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GV31geaWHtg&list=PLoKZ5qpNB0VpDVkebWd1k_GnyaXtYFhsX&index=7).

In my case, the error was:

```
"Unable to launch C:\Program Files (x86)\Qt Designer\bin\uic".
```

It turns out my uic file was in the directory

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Qt Designer"
```

To solve my case, I had to create the "bin" folder and move the uic file to it. Then I could use "form > view code".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with "when I click view code". So I'm answering two questions.

How do I preview the window in Qt Designer?
Eiter press "Ctrl+R" or in the menu bar navigate to "Form -> Preview..."

How do I use the ui file within a python script?
You need to compile your ui file to a python file. It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python).

If none of these answers your question you should try to specify your problem.

Comment: when i click in the menu bar at the top form > view code  i get the error message, i dont want the error i want the windows that show the windows with the code in c++

Answer (score 0):

Following some suggestions online, I found the "uic.exe" file in the bin directory as below:
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs{environment_name}\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin

and then created a new directory there called "bin" and moved the uic.exe file into it.

[image]

And then it worked!

[image]

Comment: how are you able to see python code? My app only shows me C++ code.