# QT python GUIs : how to view code in qt designer

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer

I want to learn to use qt designer and i want to know what to install, because I've had some issues with python versions and distributions. This is my first time doing this I know basically nothing about python or QT. I appreciate your help

Comment: Qt designer only serves to render the .ui, not for python. In the case of python use any IDE that supports python, the creators of PyQt5 offer eric IDE

Answer (score 1):

Qt Designer is just a quick way to visually define the GUI. You can then load the .ui files created there in you python application or convert them to python code: [Convert pyQt UI to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python). But I would rather recommend you to write the code from scratch by yourself. This way you can better understand how the things are actually work.

Qt is a C++ framework, if you want to use it with python you have to pick a python binding first. You basically have two choices here: PyQt and PySide. PyQt is proprietary software developed by Riverbank Computing Limited. PySide is open source software and nowadays the official Qt binding for python.

Similar to python with its major versions 2 and 3, Qt has two major versions Qt4 and Qt5 that are widely used. PyQt4 and PySide are Qt4 bindings, PyQt5 and PySide2 are Qt5 bindings.

So if you have no specific requirements regarding the version you should use, just install the latest version of Python, install PySide2 using pip and enjoy studying GUI programming with Python and Qt!