# How to transform a .ui to a .py on mac

Tags: python, pyqt

I need to transform an .ui archive to a .py but I can't use the command pyuic4, it said `command not found` in the terminal.

I already try installing pyside, pyqt, use uic.py but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python they also show how to install the required software to execute command

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally solved it. I used **pyuic5 -x Data.ui -o Data_ui.py** in the terminal, but first I opened the folder where the executable pyuic5 was, paste Data.ui and then use the line pyuic5 -x Data.ui -o Data_ui .py. Remember to open the location of the executable in the terminal before using the command