# Qt Creator as Python IDE?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I know that the routine method for using Qt framework for python(pyQt), especially for GUI applications is to use Qt Designer(for building the GUI) and after that importing that generated GUI python code into your python class and continue the logic of your application in some other IDEs like Eclipse(+PyDev) or NetBeans;

I found this post: [How to use Qt Creator with Python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264037/how-to-use-qt-creator-with-python)
but since at the time of that question, Qt Creator was at it's 2.8 version and now it's 3.1, maybe python support for Qt Creator is added(like c++); is it true?

is there anyway to use Qt Creator as a python IDE?
if 'yes', what is the code editor's features compare to other mature IDEs (like Eclipse or NetBeans)?

thanks in advance for answers;

Comment: "Code editor with C++, QML and ECMAscript support", says http://qt-project.org/wiki/category:tools::qtcreator

Comment: See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100602/developing-python-applications-in-qt-creator/24121860#24121860