# Qt Creator for Python coding, how to Clear old application output on a new run?

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator

I'm used to Qt Creator for Qt projects.

Now I'm starting with Python and I'm trying to use Qt Creator as my IDE. I've just configured it to run Python scripts (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100602/developing-python-applications-in-qt-creator)). And also set a shortcut key (Ctrl+R) to run it (following [this](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html)).

To make world perfect I'm missing one thing, Clear old application output on a new run. Actually I would like it to do the same as is done in Qt Projects. Is there someway to accomplish that?

It also will be nice to have auto save before run.

Answer (score 2):

To specify settings for displaying application output, select Tools > Options > Build & Run > General. You can select whether to open the Application Output pane on output when running or debugging applications, to clear old output on a new run, to word-wrap output, and to limit output to the specified number of lines.