# How to convert a qml file from V-Play into python?

Tags: python, qt, qml, qt-creator, v-play

I have a qml file, it looks like the below (created by [V-Play](https://felgo.com/)):

```
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.0

App {
    // You get free licenseKeys from https://v-play.net/licenseKey
    // With a licenseKey you can:
    //  * Publish your games & apps for the app stores
    //  * Remove the V-Play Splash Screen or set a custom one (available with the Pro Licenses)
    //  * Add plugins to monetize, analyze & improve your apps (available with the Pro Licenses)
    //licenseKey: "<generate one from https://v-play.net/licenseKey>"

    NavigationStack {

        Page {
            title: qsTr("My page")

        }

        AppTextField {
            id: appTextField
            x: 0
            y: 329
            width: 256
            height: 19
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        AppTextField {
            id: appTextField1
            x: 0
            y: 329
            width: 256
            height: 19
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 50
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Text {
            id: text1
            x: 0
            y: 620
            width: 24
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("A")
            font.pixelSize: 25
            anchors.horizontalCenter: appTextField1.horizontalCenter
        }

        AppButton {
            id: button
            x: 0
            y: 575
            width: 24
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("Click me please!")
            anchors.horizontalCenter: appTextField1.horizontalCenter
        }
    }
}
```

I created many PyQt5 apps, by Qt Designer, so it would be a .ui file which I could convert easily into a python file by `pyuic5`, but this is now the first time I used V-Play Qt Creator.

So now my question is:

How do I convert this into a python file (.py), as you see in the code I created two input areas (`AppTextField`), I would like it to become a python file so I can add the function which adds up the numbers in the input areas, I tried some stuff, but none of them worked, I viewed this one, [Developing Python applications in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100602/developing-python-applications-in-qt-creator), and some more, but they don't achieve my goal.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: QML is interpreted by Qt to generate graphics items. I don't think you can convert QML into Python. But, you can easily integrate this file into a python script : [http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qml.html](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qml.html)

Comment: @RomhaKorev Thanks, you should make this an answer it is very good.

Comment: Aside: I don't think the V-Play Qt Creator is any different from the normal Qt Creator except for the V-Play plugins (Getting Started and Live). I _think_ all you need is the V-Play source code to load the V-Play QML modules -- whether you're using the Qt Creator by V-Play or the one from Qt. If you can be able to get Python to work with QML... then I don't think V-Play will be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML is interpreted by Qt to generate graphics items. I don't think you can convert QML into Python.

But, you can easily integrate this file into a python script : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qml.html

```
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(QUrl('./main.qml'))
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I created a snippet from the documentation and it works: I can load my qml file into my python app. Which error do you have ?

Comment: You have to be more specific. What is the exact error ?

Comment: sorry, forgot to reply, my error is: module "Main" is not installed

Comment: Did you change the path of your qml file in my example ? You have to set the exact path of your qml file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i will try again.

Comment: Yes, it got registered!

Comment: Did you add the path to all your external QML modules (like V-Play) with the env variable QML_IMPORT_PATH or `QQmlEngine::addImportPath` ?