# Reading QWidgets values from qtDesigner .ui file to python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have `UI` file prepared using `qtcreator`.

I like to read values from `QWidgets` to python script.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398800/linking-a-qtdesigner-ui-file-to-python-pyqt) shows how to link ui file to python script.

But I can't find the information for reading values from `QWidgets` to python script.

Say I like to read user's selected value in `QSpinBox`.

I used PyQT5 for Ui design.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: In general there are 2 methods to obtain the value of a widget, but that depends on each widget, for example in your case QSlider, if you want to obtain the value in synchronic form you must use the value() method; your_slider.value(), and asynchronously using the valuechanged signal that will be issued every time the value changes, for this you must connect it to a function that receives it.